# Using `any` to indicate a wildcard value

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm writing a validator class to validate certain request objects against a known format. Rule declarations and the validator will both be written entirely in Python, and I don't need to store the structures in the DB or go across the wire in JSON or anything of that type. I'm considering using the builtin function `any` as a value to indicate that any value is permissible for a particular key.

In other words, I'm tempted to do this:

```
validation_rules = {
   "foo": ['a', 'b'],
   "bar": any
}

# Meanwhile in the validator...
for key, value in request_object.entries():
  if validation_rules[key] is any:
    # validation succeeds because this key allows any value
  elif value not in validation_rules[key]:
    # reject for invalid value
  else:
    # validation succeeds
```

Pros: it's actually really easy to read, and the semantics are reasonably clear both in the declared validation rules and in the validator. It's much more comprehensible than using `None`, which was my other idea.

Cons: It's surprising, to say the least, to see a builtin function being used in this manner, where the actual usage of the function is irrelevant and it's only being used because the name is descriptive.

If I do this, will I go to hell? Will my coworkers be mad at me? Will I get made fun of on Hacker News?

Comment: Consider using the `Any` or `object` type instead (rather than the builtin `any()` function). Or a custom marker object (e.g. `novalidate = object ()`, then `if rule is novalidate: succeed`). You might also consider using an existing validation framework like Pydantic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using a sentinel value like `any` or `None` with special-cased logic, you could create a type the implements the desired "everything goes" behavior using the same interface as the other  validation rules. Namely, checking container membership.

Python has an abstract notion of [container objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Container). Containers are any objects that define the `__contains__` special method. Such objects can be used with the membership operators `in`/`not in` just like lists or other builtin containers.

For this use case, we can define a container that treats all objects as being members of it:

```
class _Everything:
    def __contains__(self, item: Any) -> bool:
        return True

everything = _Everything()

>>> 3 in everything
True
>>> "foo" in everything
True
>>> object in everything
True
>>> everything in everything
True
```

If we swap `any` in your code with an instance of `Everything`, then your validation logic can be simplified to a single membership test:

```
validation_rules = {
   "foo": ['a', 'b'],
   "bar": everything,
}

# Meanwhile in the validator...
for key, value in request_object.entries():
  if value not in validation_rules[key]:
    # reject for invalid value
  else:
    # validation succeeds
```

As an extra bonus, this also makes it possible to give `validation_rules` a meaningful [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557920/11082165) for the purposes of static type checking. Specifically, we can mark  `validation_rules` as being a dict with values of type `Container[str]`:

```
from collections.abc import Container

validation_rules: dict[str, Container[str]] = {
   "foo": ['a', 'b'],
   "bar": everything,
}
```

Comment: Just a small nitpicking, "anything" would be better than "everything" semantically (but I don't know Python well, maybe it's a reserved keyword?)

Comment: @Kaddath I disagree, `everything` here is behaving as a set to which all things belong, whereas I'd expect an `anything` object to behave as any one thing.

Comment: The type should be `dict[str, Container[str]]`

Comment: This is a good answer for the stated requirements.  If there are other, potentially more complex rules, I would probably take it another step and use function references for the validation rules.

Comment: @JimmyJames I think this answer actually generalises really nicely using the concept of proper classes ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory) ) - the class here is defined by the predicate that returns true regardless of input and can easily be generalised into 
```class ProperClass():
    def __init__(self, predicate):   
        self.predicate = predicate
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.predicate(item)

everything = ProperClass(lambda x: True)

from numbers import Number

numbers = ProperClass(lambda x: isinstance(x, Number))
```

Comment: @CongChen There's nothing wrong with the approach given the stated requirements and I see the appeal from a mathematical view but if you generalize that approach to arbitrary rules (e.g.: valid email address), I think it would be a little arcane and confusing.

Answer (score 6):

I made the types `Anything` and `Something` for this purpose. `Anything` compares `True` with any other value, while `Something` compares `True` on anything that is not `None`:

```
>>> Anything == 42
True
>>> {'x': 10, 'y': -3} == {'x': 10, 'y': Anything}
True
>>> Anything == None
True
>>> Something == None
False
>>> Something == 1
True
```

They're available as the package [`anything` on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/anything/).

Comment: Neat concept! This answer would be more useful if it explained how the OP's business rules can be written with `Anything` and `Something`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution similar to Brian61354270's answer that's a little more generic.  You might want to use this if you have to support other rules that are more complicated.  As an example, I added regex validator:

```
import re

def in_list(*items):
  return lambda x: x in items

def any_value(value):
  return True

def regex(pattern: str):
  pattern = re.compile(pattern)
  return lambda x: pattern.fullmatch(x) is not None

validation_rules = {
   "foo": in_list('a', 'b'),
   "bar": any_value,
   "sna": regex("a.z")
}

request_object = {
   "foo": 'c',
   "bar": 'something',
   "sna": 'buz',
}

# Meanwhile in the validator...
for key, value in request_object.items():
  if not validation_rules[key](value):
    print(key, value, "no!")
  else:
    print(key, value, "yes!")
```

Comment: Stylistically I prefer this approach to the one in my answer. I takes fewer brain cycles to understand, and generalizes very nicely to more complex requirements.

Comment: Nitpicks: shadowing the builtin `all` could be confusing/bug-prone. Maybe `all` could be named something like `always_valid`? You could also save some unnecessary indirection by defining `in_list` as `def in_list(*items): return items.__contains__` :)

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks for the catch.  Yeah, shadowing built-ins is a recipe for frustration.  And using the dunder methods is definitely valid. I was erring on the side of clarity because functions that return functions can be confusing enough.